# JAVA Not a statement with ?: if statement

Tags: java

I'm getting an compilation error "Not a statement" for this line of code:

```
parallel? stats[3]++ : stats[4]++;
```

can't understand why?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html):

```
The following types of expressions can be made into a statement
by terminating the expression with a semicolon (;).

Assignment expressions
Any use of ++ or --
Method invocations
Object creation expressions

...

In addition to expression statements, there are two other kinds of
statements: declaration statements and control flow statements.
```

Obviously, your line of code above doesn't fall into any category mentioned above. Hence, the compiler throw an error. Look at the outermost, not the innermost.

Answer (score 3):

The :? operator is used to **return a value** is not a complete replacement for the if/else and you aren't returning a value. But explain better what is the complete error, and give a better look of the code not only the line that you post.

Comment: The amount of detail provided by the person asking the question is sufficient for the problem posted.